# How to add Custom Field in bootstrapTable

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-table

How to add a new custom field near the existing Search Field ("PESQUISAR") ? I saw many examples to add a new custom field bellow `tr th`, but I would like it to be in the same direction "Pesquisar" Field

[image]

### Updating

```
 <table id="table1" data-toggle="table" data-pagination=true data-sortable="true" data-search=true data-locale="pt-BR">
    <thead>

      <tr>
        <th data-sortable="true">ID</th>
        <th data-sortable="true">NOME</th>
        <th data-sortable="true">SERVICO</th>
        <th data-sortable="true">CIDADE</th>
        <th data-sortable="true">BAIRRO</th>
        <th data-sortable="true">RUA</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
       //Content
    </tbody>

</table>


<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){

   $('#table1').bootstrapTable({
     locale: 'pt-BR'
  });

 });
</script>
```

Comment: please show html markup, if you want any advise

Comment: I tried to find how this input `PESQUISAR` is being written, but did not find it

Comment: I found a `<div class="fixed-table-toolbar">`, maybe using jquery I can add a new input text, right?

Comment: are you able to share whole html page?

Comment: sorry, unfortunately I can't. but inspecting the elements I can think a way to insert it.

Comment: $('<input />').appendTo('.fixed-table-toolbar'); https://api.jquery.com/appendto/

Comment: We all can help you even if it's a non-dom element ! So please share your expected final result with the actual table layout, and it's final expected form... if it's sensitive data, just rename it with Foo Bar :)

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the toolbar table option: https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/#toolbar

You can specify a DOM element for bootstrap-table to append to it's own toolbar when it's created.